# Benefits of ServerAdmin Directive in Apache2

Tags: apache, server-administration

How exactly can the `ServerAdmin` directive in Apache2 be useful?

The Apache2 documentation reads:

> The ServerAdmin sets the contact address that the server includes in any error messages it returns to the client.

But whenever I get a 404 Error back, the email address set in my vhost  is nowhere to be seen. Do I need some extra Directive to make it work?

**vhost:**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
    ServerName testsite.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/www
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: 2022 update: it's required by `mod_md`, which uses it to register you at a Certificate Authority when getting a TLS certificate. The CA may or may not use it to contact you.

Comment: This question is probably more suitable to "Unix and Linux" https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Apparently that functionality of Apache has been deprecated.  I used to see a message in the event of an error to contact the server administrator, but now can't get it to happen on the current versions.

As an answer to your question "how can it be useful"; you can get the value with PHP at least
[$_SERVER['SERVER_ADMIN']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and return that from your code in the event of an error.

Comment: The information is just not displayed as default, not deprecated. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As default the `ServerAdmin` information is not displayed on error messages.

You can display this information enabling the `ServerSignature` directive to the `email` value:

```
ServerAdmin foo@example.com
ServerSignature email
```

Relevant documentation:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveradmin

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serversignature

Then remember to restart your Apache HTTPd server:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

NOTE: You can also use an URL, instead of an email. That's very useful if you have a contact page instead of an email address.